# Extract a string of numbers and symbols with regular expression with using php preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

what regular expression i must use if i want to extract "-i123213131345" from URL like this  `http://example.com/blabla-bla-i123213131345/blabla`

Comment: I have tried with something like '/(-i _[0-9])/' but without success

Comment: Why would that work? There's no underscore in there... `/-i\d+/`

Comment: Neither is there any quantifier in the pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `-i[0-9]+` pattern.

Sample:

```
$str = 'http://example.com/blabla-bla-i123213131345/blabla';
$pattern = '/-i[0-9]+/';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/uAZo95)

[Here's](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) useful tool to play with regexes before you implement them. Also it helps a lot to learn `Regex`.

Comment: So much of an effort for a new user :P

Comment: @Jari Question was not well-formed but it was new user's mistake. ;)